# Can't access staging server via IP

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to transfer a wordpress site from one server to a new one and I don't want to take my site down during the process. The site is currently running on its original server and I just set up a new server via Laravel Forge / AWS.

What I had planned on doing was to get the site set up on the new server by navigating to the numeric IP address of the new server while the site is still active via the domain / original server. This isn't working however. When I try to navigate to the IP of the new server, it is redirecting automatically to the domain which is just taking me to my original server.

I thought maybe this was an issue with the nginx config file but can't see anything in there that would explain this behavior. I'm a noob though so posting it here:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/airfrying.net/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name airfrying.net;
    root /home/forge/airfrying.net/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/airfrying.net/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/airfrying.net-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/airfrying.net/after/*;
```

I also tried setting up an A record to point to staging.airfrying.net at my new IP but that is also redirecting to the original site.... Frustrating! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A better way to test is to put the IP of the new machine into the hosts file of your PC, flush dns (close browser, cmd prompt, then use "ipconfig /flushdns"). Your new config doesn't appear to include any 301 redirects. Please check your Nginx access and error logs, your PHP error logs, and you can turn on PHP access logs if you want. The answer is probably in the logs, combined with a config file you haven't included - but I don't know which one.

Comment: Yes, the logs show that it is 301 185 redirecting.... but still not sure why or how....

Answer (score 1):

Your new WordPress site contains the name of your old website in the HOME and SITEURL variables which are set via the `wp-config.php` file or the site's control panel. See [this document](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for more.

You could set these values to use the IP address for the hostname, or by omitting the scheme and hostname altogether (e.g. `/blog`).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it was actually a combination of multiple issues. I did have to edit the wp-config.php file as suggested by @Richard above. That didn't solve it alone. I also had to edit the nginx config file as well as follows.

I had to change:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name airfrying.net;
    .....
```

to this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my_ip_address_here;
```